# In spoken Italian, is there a standard way to encode the letters of words when there is too much noise and the words cannot be heard?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

In Italy, it seems common to use city names (rather than names of other things) when spelling words out in noisy environments where the words themselves cannot be heard clearly. I have gathered a list of these and have used, for each letter, the name of the largest (or most well known) Italian city I was aware of which begins with such letter (this way the names should be more likely to be recognized across all of Italy):

- A di Ancona o Agrigento
- B di Bari o Bologna o Bergamo
- C di Cagliari o Como
- D di Domodossola
- E di Empoli o Enna
- F di Firenze
- G di Genova
- H di ???
- I di Imperia o Imola
- J di ???Jesolo
- K di ???
- L di Lecce o Lucca o Lecco
- M di Modena o Mantova
- N di Napoli
- O di Oristano
- P di Palermo o Pordenone o Pisa
- Q di ???Quintilio
- R di Roma
- S di Salerno o Savona
- T di Torino
- U di Urbino
- V di Venezia o Varese o Vercelli
- W di ???
- X di ???
- Y di ???
- Z di ???

  1. What's the best way to fill in the blanks above, and is there a standard assignment anywhere of letters to (city) names that works for Italians? ([this link](http://www.mangeruca.com/towns.htm) may help answer the question).
  2. The [NATO Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) is an example of a standardized code which maps each letter to a word, just as described above, in a standardized manner, (and is only used by people who work in specific areas such as the military and law enforcement). I wonder whether in Italy standardized codes made up in this manner exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your assignation is not standard (even if there is not an official standard): for instance, for M most people would pick *Milano*, and to connect a letter and a city name one often uses *come* (“D come Domodossola”).

Anyway, there is an [Italian Wikipedia article](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_telefonico_italiano) about the so-called “Alfabeto telefonico italiano”, which gives the following table (here simplified to a single option when there is more than one; see the complete table and its sources in the article):

A come Ancona
B come Bari
C come Como
D come Domodossola
E come Empoli
F come Firenze
G come Genova
H come hotel
I come Imola
J semplicemente "i lunga"
K semplicemente "cappa"
L come Livorno
M come Milano
N come Napoli
O come Otranto
P come Palermo
Q semplicemente "qu"
R come Roma
S come Savona
T come Torino
U come Udine
V come Venezia
W semplicemente "vu doppia"
X semplicemente "ics"
Y semplicemente "ipsilon"
Z come Zara

In specialised contexts, especially aviation, NATO alphabet (Alfa, Bravo, Charlie...) is commonly used in Italy too.

Comment: Mi piacie la "Z come Zara" perchè mi ricorda proprio il dover "star là a guardare"! ;-D

Comment: Had to learn the NATO alphabet for both my glider license and my radio amateur license (long ago). As an aside: The "alfabeto telefonico italiano" is widely known but is not a matter of course, as the following shows: I was asked to leave my name in an office. I said: "Torino Roma Otranto Savona Savona". The secretary wrote down something, then asked: "Torino Roma può bastare?"

Comment: I forgot: since then I always say: "Tross, __che si scrive__ Torino Roma Otranto Savona Savona"

Answer (score 1):

A meno che non si faccia  riferimento all'alfabeto NATO, comunemente  io sento usare queste definizioni, (trattandosi di lettere non comuni all'alfabeto italiano):

- H di hotel
- K di K (come si pronuncia)
- Q di quadro
- W di Washington
- Y ( ipsilon)
- Z (zeta)

K Y e Z sono chiaramente distinguibili nella loro definizione.

Comment: Grazie del tuo contributo, userò questo modo di fare lo spelling anch'io. E per quanto riguarda le altre lettere, secondo te, va bene così?

Comment: Direi di si, stiamo parlando di un modo informale di fare lo spelling. Avendo la lingua italiana  una scrittura che spesso corrisponde alla pronuncia, lo spelling non viene usato spesso come in inglese.

Comment: E va bene, mollo. La ragione per la quale ho chiesto questa domanda è che ho un nome straniero e tutte le volte che ho dovuto fare lo spelling del mio nome (,per far capire agli altri come si scriveva, mi sono trovato impacciato, non sapendo che cosa dire. Macchèmmefrega se non posso neanche esprimermi liberamente!!!?? Quindi, adesso sapete il mio segreto. Tanti ringraziamenti, e grazie per le risposte, ora conosco l'Italia anch'io.

Comment: Già , se ti fossi chiamato Giacomo Madinto ( just an italianization of your name) it would be much easier :). You are welcome!

Comment: Isacco Perlini mi viene a momento.

Comment: Good, no spelling needed!!